# Show $f(x,y)=\frac{\log(1+x^2y^2)}{x^2}$ $(x\neq 0)$, $f(x,y)=y^2$ $(x=0)$ is $C^1$

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Consider $f\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ given by
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}\frac{\log(1+x^2y^2)}{x^2}\end{aligned}&\text{if }x\neq 0,\\
y^2&\text{if }x=0.\end{cases}
$$
I need to show that $f$ is a $C^1$ function. I’ve already shown that $f$ is differentiable. I'm having trouble showing that the partial derivates are continuous at $\vec 0$. I've calculated that $D_1f(\vec 0)=D_2f(\vec 0)=0.$ So I need to show that for $x\neq 0$:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{2xy^2}{x^2(1+x^2y^2)}-\frac{2\log(1+x^2y^2)}{x^3}=0.
$$
I tried Taylor expansion, but I still don't know how to show it entirely:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{2xy^2}{x^2(1+x^2y^2)}-\frac{2x^2y^2+O(x^4y^4)}{x^3}=\frac{2y^2}{x(1+x^2y^2)}-\frac{2y^2+O(x^2y^4)}{x}.$$
It even seems that this limit doesn't exist. I'm guessing I made a mistake somewhere, but I wouldn't know where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you actually have to show continuity of the partial derivatives at any point with $x=0$, not just the origin. By far the easiest way to work with this function is with its Taylor series, uniformly convergent on compact sets whenever $|xy|<1$. Note that
$$\log(1+u) = u-\frac{u^2}2+\frac{u^3}3-\dots \quad\text{whenever } |u|<1,$$
and so we have
$$f(x,y)= y^2-\frac{x^2y^4}2+\frac{x^4y^6}3-\dots \quad\text{whenever } |xy|<1.$$
(Note that there is no longer any need to specify $x=0$ or $x\ne 0$.) In particular, $f$ is real analytic (given by a convergent power series) in a neighborhood of any point of the $y$ axis and is hence $C^\infty$ along the $y$-axis. It is obviously $C^\infty$ elsewhere (being the quotient of a $C^\infty$ function by a nonzero $C^\infty$ function).